# How to send information from one window to another? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I send information from one wpf window to another window. What I wanted is for `string filepath` to save the information it gets the first time it is called.

This is the problem, when I click `button1` from window1.xmal.cs it calls `openfile()` from DocumentManager.cs. And when I access `filepath` from window2.xmal.cs it gives an empty string. I want to save the filepath string I got from when it was called from window1.xmal.cs.

Here is what I have:

window1.xmal.cs

```
DocumentManager mgr = new DocumentManager();

private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        ImageSource imgsource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(mgr.openfile().ToString())); 
        themeImage.Source = imgsource;
}
```

DocumentManager.cs

```
public string filePath;
public object openfile() {
    OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
    bool? result = open.ShowDialog();

    if (result == true) {
        filePath = open.FileName;  
    }
    return filePath;
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't declare your document manager instance in a button click event, unless you don't mind the instance being lost forever as soon as it goes out of scope...

Comment: oh actually I dont have it like that in my code. Let me fix that.

Comment: The first answer post I made solved that, and I've edited my answer to include sending the ImageSource to Window2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is the way you are instantiating the `DocumentManager` class.
I've made an example that works. Here's the code:

**MainWindow**

```csh
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{   DocumentManager mgr;       
    Window2 w2;
    public MainWindow() { InitializeComponent(); }
    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {  mgr = new DocumentManager(); w2 = new Window2(); w2.Show(); }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { ImageSource imgsource; string imglocation;
        try {
            imglocation = mgr.openfile().ToString();
            imgsource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imglocation));
            result.Text = imglocation;
            w2.imgsource = imgsource;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
    }
}
```

**DocumentManager**

```csh
class DocumentManager
{
    public string filePath;
    public string openfile()
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog open = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        bool? result = open.ShowDialog();
        if (result == true) { filePath = open.FileName; }
        else { filePath = "Nothing Opened"; }
        return filePath;
    }
}
```

**MainWindow XAML**

```csh
<Window x:Class="CrossClassDialog.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="120" Width="350" Loaded="MainWindow_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click"/>
       <TextBlock x:Name="result" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,30,0,0"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Window2 XAML**

```csh
<Window x:Class="CrossClassDialog.Window2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window2" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Image x:Name="OpenedImage" Source="{Binding ImageSource}" />
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

**Add this property in Window2**

```csh
    private ImageSource _imgsource;
    public ImageSource imgsource
    {
        get { return _imgsource; }
        set 
        { 
            _imgsource = value;
            OpenedImage.Source = value;
        }
    }
```

By the way, I changed a few things like the type your `openfile()` method returns.

Comment: But, I need to know how would I be able to get the `string imglocation` to show in another window (window2.xmal.cs) without having to call `openfile()` again.

Comment: @FJam I've added a second window and use a property to update the image in there.

Comment: Mind you, this could be made a lot cleaner. It's not MVVM, not thread safe, etc. But it works. for the future, I would recommend you look into events for passing data between classes.